# how to get deleted data from tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

Can anyone help me retrieve deleted data in Oracle SQL*Plus?

here are the two tables that the data has been deleted from.be informed that only data of current date (T_DT = 28-JUN-15') has been accidentally deleted and the sales center id (SC_CD) selected as 27.

```
SQL> desc targ_mas
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 SC_CD                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 FP_ID                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
 T_DT                            NOT NULL DATE
 T_PCT                                    NUMBER(3)
 T_TARG                                   NUMBER(9,2)
 FL_MVH                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> desc prod_targ
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 ASM_ID                                   VARCHAR2(4)
 RM_ID                                    VARCHAR2(4)
 FM_ID                                    VARCHAR2(4)
 FP_ID                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
 SC_CD                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 TYP_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 DIV_CD                                   VARCHAR2(1)
 CAT_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 PRD_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
 T_DT                            NOT NULL DATE
 QTY_TARG                                 NUMBER(8,2)
 T_VAL                                    NUMBER(10,2)
 TP_VAL                                   NUMBER(9,2)
 BR_CD                                    VARCHAR2(3)
 BS_CD                                    VARCHAR2(4)
 RMBS_CD                                  VARCHAR2(2)
```

queries used to delete data from both tables :

```
delete from targ_mas
where sc_cd = '27'
and t_dt = '28-JUN-15'


delete from prod_targ
where sc_cd = '27'
and t_dt = '28-JUN-15'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this change has already been committed, your best hope is that you have flashback enabled. If you do, you could, for instance, retrieve it into a table created for this purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE targ_mas_recov AS (
    SELECT * AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSDATE - 1 # E.g., the data from yesterday
    FROM   targ_mas
    WHERE  sc_cd = '27' AND t_dt = '28-JUN-15'
);

CREATE TABLE prod_targ_recov AS (
    SELECT * AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSDATE - 1 # E.g., the data from yesterday
    FROM prod_targ
    WHERE sc_cd = '27' AND t_dt = '28-JUN-15'
);
```

Alternatively, if no other update/delete/insert statements that you want to preserve were performed on these table, you could just flashback them directly:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE targ_mas TO TIMESTAMP SYSDATE - 1;
FLASHBACK TABLE prod_targ TO TIMESTAMP SYSDATE - 1;
```

If these changes were already committed and you do not have flashback enabled, I'm afraid your only option would be to recover from backup.

Comment: Mureinik,flashback is not enbaled.just checked the status from v$database.

thanks for the solutions.